# how to get zone redundant storage availability areas programmatically

Tags: azure

How can I check ZRS availability zones programmatically? Is there some API? 
There is a list of regions where ZRS is supported, I need to get those programmatically.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get this information programmatically. Please check the below documentation to get the list of ZRS supported regions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy-zrs#support-coverage-and-regional-availability